# html single submit button used for two different tasks

Tags: html, jsp

I've a html button which I want for two different tasks on a single press event. First, when I press the submit button it should **insert data to the database** (which I've done) and the another task is to **render to another page**. How can I make this button do these two functions simultaneously?

Comment: What do you mean by render page? Do you mean redirect, or perhaps show something in an iframe? What language(s) are you using on your back-end? Front-end? What have you tried so far? Do you have a code snippet you can show us that we can work from?

Comment: What language/platform do you use at the backend/server side? E.g.to insert data into database?

Comment: How does the button know which thing the user wants to do?

Comment: @Zhihao I am using jsp & for JohnFx the user do not need to know the function of the submit button. Only thing is that the submit button should perform the two tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specyfing `action` attribute of `form` element:

```
<form method="post" action="page.jsp?action=save">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

After clicking `submit` button user is redirected to `page.jsp` (it may be the same page) and in that file you can get value of `action` variable: if it's `save` then execute code responsible for writing to db. After that code you place page-rendering code.

It's the simplest solution, but maybe not the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

"Just" do it then.

```
someDAO.save(someData);
response.sendRedirect(newURL);
```

That's basically all you need to execute in your servlet (or JSP if you're still abusing it as a controller).